# Reformat how JSON is compiled in response

Tags: c#, json, endpoint

Wrote an endpoint that loops through a date range and for each new date it calls a Stored Procedure in SQL to collect data from that date. Basically the Results I'm getting are sales from each department in a specific store. This is how the JSON response looks :

```json
 {
  "12/3/2022": [
         {
             "Department": "1101",
             "Total $": 1887.30
         },
         {
             "Department": "6021",
             "Total $": 19.45
         },
         {
             "Department": "6030",
             "Total $": 247.33
         }
     ],
     "12/4/2022": [
         {
             "Department": "1101",
             "Total $": 1942.62
         },
         {
             "Department": "6021",
             "Total $": 0.46
         },
         {
             "Department": "6030",
             "Total $": 488.13
         }
    ]
}
```

But I'd really like to have this displayed with departments as the header. So, something like this :

```json
{
 "1101": [
        {
           "12/3/2022": 1887.30,
            "12/4/2022": 1942.62
        }
        ],
 "6021": [
        {
           "12/3/2022": 19.45,
           "12/4/2022": 0.46
        }
   ],
  "6030": [
         {
             "12/3/2022": 247.33,
             "12/4/2022": 488.13
         }
   ]
}
```

This is my code for collecting the data :

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetWeeklyStoreSummary(int appid, string fromDate, string endDate, string store)
{
    ResponseHandler response = new ResponseHandler(this.Request);
    WeeklyStoreSummaryHelper ws = new WeeklyStoreSummaryHelper();

    try
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(appid);
        WeeklyStoreSummaryDBAdapter db = new WeeklyStoreSummaryDBAdapter(connectionString);

        DataSet result;

        foreach (DateTime day in ws.EachDay(fromDate, endDate)) 
        {
            var currentDate = day.ToShortDateString();
            result = db.GetWeeklySummary(currentDate, store);
            response.AddTable(currentDate, result.Tables[0]);
        }

        string jsonResponse = response.GetJsonResponse();
        return response.RequestCompleted(jsonResponse);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException a)
    {
        return response.BadRequest(a.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return response.GenericError(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse your json into Dictionary and then use LINQ to build another dictionary.